# Gradle Findbugs evaluate subprojects but not root project with a root task

Tags: gradle, findbugs

I'm looking to be able to create a task in my root project that executes all findbugs tasks for all of my subprojects.  My root project has no source.

```
test_automation
--fixtures
--functional
--services
--utilities
```

I've got a task: `task findbugs(dependsOn: ['findbugsMain', 'findbugsTest'])`

I configure findbugsMain:

```
findbugsMain {
    source subprojects.collect{project -> project.fileTree(project.sourceSets.main.output.classesDir)}
    excludes = ['**/test_automation/build/**'] //root project's source
}
```

However when I execute, I get an error:

```
:findbugsMain (Thread[main,5,main]) started.
:findbugsMain
file or directory '/Users/ahumerickhouse/codebase/test_automation/build/classes/main', not found
Executing task ':findbugsMain' (up-to-date check took 0.249 secs) due to:
  No history is available.
file or directory '/Users/ahumerickhouse/codebase/test_automation/build/classes/main', not found
:findbugsMain FAILED
:findbugsMain (Thread[main,5,main]) completed. Took 0.279 secs.
```

I can't figure out how to remove the root directory's source from the build.  It's in there because it's configured prior to my additions.  Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

***EDIT***
I want the reports in the root directory for all of the subprojects, that's why I'm trying to do this.  I was able to do this simply with CodeNarc:

```
codenarcMain {
    source subprojects.collect {project -> project.sourceSets.main.groovy.srcDirs }
}

codenarcTest {
    source subprojects.collect {project -> project.sourceSets.test.groovy.srcDirs }
}

task codenarc(type:CodeNarc, dependsOn:['codenarcMain', 'codenarcTest'])
```

Comment: You say "I'm looking to be able to create a task in my root project that executes all findbugs tasks for all of my subprojects", but the code tries to configure a single findbugs task to analyze the sources of all subprojects. If the root project doesn't have any code, it typically wouldn't have plugins such as `java` and `findbugs` applied, and hence it wouldn't have a `findbugsMain` task either.

Comment: Right, I don't want it applied to the root directory, I want to ignore the root directory classes while executing FindBugs.  The end result I'm looking for is to execute `findbugs` from root.  That will execute across all subprojects and report back into `findbugs/build/reports` instead of all the individual subprojects.

Answer (score 1):

$rootDir/build.gradle:

```
subprojects {
    task findbugsAll {
        dependsOn tasks.withType(FindBugs)
    }
}
```

Execute with:

```
$ gradle findbugsAll
```

Comment: This executes all the tasks, but the tasks are executed from the subprojects.  I want the task executed from the root project and look through the subprojects.  This way all the reports are all combined into one place instead of over 4 subprojects.

Comment: In that case, the root project should declare one or more `FindBugs` tasks, rather than applying the `java` and `findbugs` plugins. That's a better solution than overriding sources with `source = ...`.